# Check if isset and echo "name" on the screen

Tags: php, get, echo

I'm a noob and I started learning PHP. I made a simple form and I wanted to get the name I enter inside the browser with "ECHO". I figured out that I have to use "if isset" and I successfully wrote that solution. But I struggle to put it in one line, please help:

```
<form action="UserInput.php" method="get">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name">
        <input type="submit">
</form>

/* This is working great!
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        echo $_GET['name'];
       } else {
        // do nothing
       }
    ?>
*/
```

I want to check if 'name' was entered and if entered echo $_GET['name']; otherwise I want the value for 'name' to be 'anonymous'. According to the documentation here's what I wrote:

```
  $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? echo $_GET['name']; : 'anonymous';
```

I know my error is in `echo $_GET['name'];`. I just don't know how to formulate the showing of 'name' on the screen with 'echo'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `echo` when you're assigning a variable.

```
$name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : 'anonymous';
echo $name;
```

In modern PHP you can use the null-coalescing operator:

```
$name = $_GET['name'] ?? 'anonymous';
echo $name;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! There is just one mistake. Remove the semicolon after $_GET['name']; and wrote it like $_GET['name'] then it worked. Thank you for the short version.